# Do I need to Unsubscribe from the `route.params` observable if they are used inside a dynamic component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

1- Create a dynamic component.

2- Subscribe to `route.params` observable.

3- Inject the dynamic component into some component.

4- Destroy and re-create the dymamic component.

Do I need to Unsubscribe from the `route.params` observable if they are used inside a  dynamic component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732897/8286262), you should:

> Unsubscribe from the ActivatedRoute observables like route.params if
>   they are subscribed inside a nested (Added inside tpl with the
>   component selector) or dynamic component as they may be subscribed
>   many times as long as the parent/host component exists. No need to
>   unsubscribe from them in other scenarios as mentioned in the quote
>   above from Routing & Navigation docs.